# process.env variable is undefined inside the function and not outside (React)

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, undefined

Here is a code sample recreating the issue:

```
console.log(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL!}api/pay/payment_intents`);

const handleSubmit = async (e: React.SyntheticEvent) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log(`url inside submit: ${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_ULR!}api/pay/payment_intents`);
}
```

I don't know why but *process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL* is correct outside the function and is udefined inside the function, any idea why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote `process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_ULR` inside function, ULR, not URL